# vba powerpoint for mac creating unwanted blank line

Tags: vba, powerpoint, microsoft365

I am trying to use a PowerPoint macro written for Windwos on a Mac (Microsoft 365 for Mac). Most of it is working well, but there are two strange things. The major issue: The Mac creates unwanted blank lines.

`TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "Text 1" & vbCrLf & "Text 2" & vbCrLf & "Text 3"`

& vbCrLf & creates just a break on Windows PPT, but an additional blank line on the Mac. Any ideas how I can avoid that?

There is a minor issue, too:
I thought it's better to use TextFrame2 instead of TextFrame all time, but on the Mac I get a compiling error, when trying to use it with the ruler function close to the end of the code. If anyone has a solution for this, I would be happy, too.

```
Private Sub ParameterColumnBodyStandard()

Dim shp As Shape
Dim i As Integer
    
Set shp = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

With shp
    .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
    .Line.Visible = msoFalse
With .TextFrame2
    .TextRange.Text = "Text 1" & vbCrLf & "Text 2" & vbCrLf & "Text 3"
    .VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorTop
    .MarginBottom = 5.6692878
    .MarginLeft = 5.6692878
    .MarginRight = 5.6692878
    .MarginTop = 5.6692878
    .WordWrap = msoTrue
With .TextRange
    .Font.Size = 16
    .Font.Name = "Arial"
    .Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    .Font.Bold = msoFalse
    .Font.Italic = msoFalse
    .Font.UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
    .ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 6
    .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignLeft
    .ParagraphFormat.Bullet.UseTextColor = msoFalse
    .ParagraphFormat.Bullet.UseTextFont = msoFalse
    .ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    .Characters(1, 6).Font.Bold = msoFalse
                For i = 2 To 3
With .Paragraphs(i).ParagraphFormat.Bullet
    .Visible = msoTrue
End With
                Next
With .Paragraphs(2)
    .ParagraphFormat.IndentLevel = 2
    .ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Character = 8226
    .ParagraphFormat.Bullet.RelativeSize = 1
End With
With .Paragraphs(3)
    .ParagraphFormat.IndentLevel = 3
    .ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Character = 8226
    .ParagraphFormat.Bullet.RelativeSize = 1
End With
End With
End With
With .TextFrame
With .Ruler
     .Levels(2).FirstMargin = 14.173219
     .Levels(2).LeftMargin = 28.346439
     .Levels(3).FirstMargin = 28.346439
     .Levels(3).LeftMargin = 42.519658
End With
End With
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Use _vbCr_ instead. That should work identically on both Windows and Mac.

Comment: It does. Thank you, John!